# Unable to generate tkinter scrollbar

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

```
self.root = tkinter.Tk()

self.frame = Frame(self.root, width = 1300, height = 1300, bg = "yellow")
self.frame.grid(row = 0 , column = 0, sticky = 'nw')
self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.frame.grid_propagate(True)

self.canvas_main = Canvas(self.frame, 
                      height = 300, 
                      width = 300,
                      scrollregion=(500,500,0,500)
                      )

 self.canvas_main.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx= 10, pady = 10, sticky = "news")

 self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.root, orient = VERTICAL, command = self.canvas_main.yview)
 self.scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')
 self.canvas_main.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
```

In above code block, I have entered Scrollbar element for enabling vertical scrollbar however, it does not reflect. Can anyone find out what I am doing wrong in this block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the scrollable region (`scrollregion`) to be zero pixels tall, so tkinter thinks there's nothing to be scrolled in the vertical direction.

Often you will do your drawing first and then set the scrollable region to encompass everything you've drawn. You do this by getting the *bounding box* -- the smallest rectangle that includes all of the canvas objects -- and then using that as the value for `scrollregion`.

Example:

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(...)
<draw a bunch of objects>
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

The other method is to define ahead of time how big the virtual drawing area is. For example, you've set your canvas to have a width and height of 300. If you want the actual drawing area to be twice the visible size then you could set the `scrollregion` to an area twice that big.

This example sets the scrollable region to begin at 0,0 (the upper left corner), and extend to 600,600 (the bottom right corner):

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(..., width=300, height=300)
canvas.configure(scrollregion=(0,0,600,600)
```

Comment: I am little confused. How can I set scrollbar value?

Comment: @NehaBhushan: that's what setting the `scrollregion` does. It defines the area of the canvas that is scrollable.